# Change Destination Branch for a Commit

Tags: gerrit

Can I change the "destination-branch" for a Code Review on Gerrit? For example, the incoming change request is configured to merge into `develop`, but I see this will break things. Can I change the destination branch for that change request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the destination branch.

You need to **Cherry Pick** the change to the other branch using the appropriate button in the Gerrit UI or manually pushing another change to Gerrit and then you can **Abandon** the previous one.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that I can choose the branch when I cherry-pick. Thanks!